# Any Way to Throttle Google Chrome CPU/RAM Usage in OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, memory, cpu

Google Chrome uses quite a bit of RAM and processing power on my Mac. It's a fairly new (Early 2015) Macbook Pro with 16GB of ram and 2.9Ghz CPU. Still google chrome always shows up on apps using significant energy, burns through my battery quickly and causes my laptop to heat up to unsafe temperatures.

It's just a web-browser I can't believe it's 2016 and it takes up so much energy to run regardless of having 20-70 tabs open.

Is there any way to throttle its consumption of power? What is causing it to do this? I've tried other web browsers (Safari, Firefox, Opera, and Tor) and all end up using a lot of energy similar to Chrome. In terms of modifying the code, would it be possible to have the tabs all open but turn off the webpage not being viewed, then when you switch to that tab it re-loads the page without closing the tab?

Comment: And how much, exactly, is “quite a bit”? Chrome has an integrated “Task Manager”. Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: I won't include the screenshot because I do not want to share my browser tabs out of privacy concern, but I've just taken a look at the Task Manager and of all the tabs the RAM usage for Chrome is 450mb and CPU ranges from 30-1.

Comment: How is that “quite a bit”? Also, Chrome starts multiple processes, manually account for that is very difficult. You can just remove tab titles with your favorite image editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer space to provide illustrations...

I think your estimate of how much RAM 20 - 70 tabs is using is way off. In activity monitor you need to show All Processes, Hierarchically then sort by Process Name to be able to view all the dependencies of any given process.

You then need to add up all those figures, not just take the 'global' figure at the top.

I don't use Chrome, but here's a picture of Safari with 20 or so tabs open.

[image]

This won't help your memory usage in itself, but it may help to understand where that's coming from.

A similar picture showing by CPU would show that web pages, unless they have video etc running, don't really use CPU much at all.

[image]

Note also that CPU is reported by Activity Monitor *per core* so you need to divide that figure by the number of virtual cores you have.
If you're not sure of that figure, just hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  in Activity Monitor & count the stripes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use something like Tab Suspender or The Great Suspender (both fairly buggy unfortunately, I currently use the latter - Github version not chrome store) which will likely do 90% of what you want by automatically unloading background tabs after a set amount of inactivity, reloading on access.

As a reference my Chrome currently totals 7.7 GB RAM and ~10% of one core, but that's with almost 300 tabs and 20-30 extensions.

Also mandatory: good adblock (uBlock or via hosts) + preventing autoplay of plugins and (increasingly a culprit) HTML5 video.

Every so often you still get a glitched out tab maxing a core, you could maybe write a script to automatically pause or throttle these with something like cpulimit.

Another good trick is using signals to completely pause processes, ie. `pkill -STOP Chrome` would freeze all Chrome processes including the helpers, `pkill -CONT Chrome` to reverse. STOP and CONT is what I generally use instead of quitting apps, mainly because I have more RAM than sense.